# SDL2 - Why is a text flickering if my color is not initialized as a private variable?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I try to present text with the following code:

```
void Text::display(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y) {
// pos is an SDL_Rect and font is a TTF_Font
    pos.x = pos.w = x;
    pos.y = pos.h = y;

    SDL_Surface *surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &pos.w, &pos.h);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &pos);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}
```

In my **Text** class. At first I had an uninitialized `SDL_Color color` in my `Text::display()` method which let me present a text on the screen. (`renderer` is passed from main + coordinates `x,y`). But I decided to make my `SDL_Color color` a private variable in the class `Text` instead. And what is weird to me is that as a private variable the text was flickering once I presented it, but if I set it as a public variable or placed it in the method the text was not flickering. Or if I initialized it as a private variable (`SDL_Color color = {255, 255, 255}`).

**My question is** if there was only pure luck that it worked when `color` was uninitialized as a public or method variable or if they are treated differently? When I initialized color in the constructor it was also flickering if color was private.

*My main method:*

```
void fpsCap(Uint32 starting_tick) {
    if ((1000 / fps) > SDL_GetTicks() - starting_tick) {
        SDL_Delay(1000 / fps - (SDL_GetTicks() - starting_tick));
    }
}

int main(int argv, char** args) {

// Create renderer, window, etc

    while (true) {
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        Text *txt = new Text("hello");
        txt->display(gui->getRenderer(), 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You leak an instance of Text in every iteration. Use a local variable (i.e. `Text` instead of `Text *`), there is no need for `new` here.

Comment: @Frax ah yes I didnt put up my entire project since it is a lot of code but the `Text *` is meant to be outside the loop. When should I use `new` then? I am a bit used to Java where we were told to use it for every new object we wanted to use.

Comment: @darclander you shound use dynamic allocation when you don't expect to delete it right away by the end of your code block (e.g. loading a texture, but even that may be up to the question), or when object is too large to fit on stack (we still have quite limited stack space, usually 1-8 megabytes total).

Comment: @keltar what is the downside of dynamic memory allocation besides memory leaks etc then? Is it just safer to stick with storing objects on the stack? If we *could* would it be better to store everything dynamically?

Comment: Added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @darclander that's a separate question, but stack allocations cost nothing at all (entire 'allocation' is just shifting stack top, once when you enter function (or, sometimes, code block), not even once for each variable but literally just once), you can't forget to free it even if exception or longjump happens, and they are very likely to already be in CPU cache. Actually java sometimes detects variable is local and uses stack too, but you don't control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the private member is not initialized, and so it gets random/garbage value. As you allocate new Text instance for every frame. You allocate on heap (every time in a new place), so it is sort of guaranteed to actually be garbage.

Why it didn't flicker in other cases?

- Public member: my guess is that you also made it static? Static variables are zero-initialized (contrary to member variables).
- Local variable: local variables are not zeroed and are considered to contain garbage, but as they are stack-allocated, they are likely to get identical piece of garbage every single time in the given place.
- Private member assigned in the constructor: that is unexpected. Are you sure that it was the same constructor that is actually used? And that it was the same variable? Perhaps some name shadowing prevented the value from actually landing where our should?

Tangential:

You leak a Text instance every loop. You should `delete` every object created with `new`, or better, avoid using `new` altogether. Use unique_ptr/make_unique instead, or just local variables (much better in this case).

EDIT to answer questions about `new`:

In modern C++ you almost never need to use `new`.

- If you have an object that is used only during the execution of the function, the natural thing to do is to keep it directly (i.e. not through a pointer), in this case defining the variable as

  ```
  Text txt("hello");
  ```

  This is a similar idiom to Java's `Text txt = new Text("hello");`, but the result variable is an instance itself, and not a reference to it.
- If you want to create an instance that you immediately pass as an argument of type `Text` or `const Text&`, you can create it as temporary like `SomeFunction(Text("hello"))` (note the lack of `new`, it's just the class name).
- If you need heap allocation, smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) created with [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) are
  strongly preferred, as they guard from many common pitfalls such as memory leaks and dangling pointers, at least as long as you keep hold of the smart pointer itself. `std::shared_ptr` is probably closest thing standard C++ has to Java reference, although it's not garbage collected, so if you make a cycle of them, they won't be ever freed.

  You could replace your `Text *txt = new Text("hello");` with

  ```
  auto txt = std::make_unique<Text>("hello");
  ```

  to get the same behavior, but with the `Text` getting destroyed and deallocated at the end of the block.

Comment: Maybe I initialized the private member incorrectly in the constructor but what made me confused was that I did not make it a `public static` variable either. The reasoning behind why if it was allocated on the stack or on the heap helped me a bit though. As I answered you in the previous comment, is it bad to use `new` in this case?

Comment: Added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: even if it was not part of my original question it helps understand a bit why the values are given gibberish values. I think it explains my question very well!